What is wrong in this code (sine value print)?
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void){ 
    double x;
    printf("Input a number betwen 0 and 1: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("\aThe sine of x is %f\n", sin(x));
    return 0;
}

When I run the code the terminal shows value as 0.000000

You need "%lf" to scanf a double. You should also check the return value from scanf.

Your compiler isn't telling you what the problem is? (For gcc and clang, adding -Wall -Wextra to the compiler options is a good start)

The %f format specifier to scanf expects a float * as a parameter.  You're passing in a double *.  Using the wrong format specifier for the type triggers undefined behavior in your code, which in this case is giving you strange results.
You need to use %lf to accept a double *.
scanf("%lf", &x);


As mentioned in comments, it may be worth amending this to speak to best practices about validating input, as the OP neither checks the return value of scanf nor ensures the value input is actually between 0 and 1.
